# Can't see Swift variable/method in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am unable to see the method/variable to set `myVar` to `true` from Objective C even tough I've added the `@objc` and `public` modifiers and there is no `Bool` in the `setMyVarTrue()` method's signature.

This is probably caused by the difference between Swift's `Bool` and Objective C's `BOOL`.

Other class methods/variables are visible, just this particular one isn’t.

How is is possible to set Swift's `Bool` from Objective C?

Swift code:

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    public var myVar:Bool = false

    @objc public func setMyVarTrue() {
        self.myVar = true
    }
}
```

Objective C code:

```
MyViewController* myViewController = [MyViewController new];
myViewController.myVar = true // Variable not found
myViewController.setMyVarTrue() // Method not found
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have you imported the *modulename*-swift.h file?  Are your property and method visible in that file?

Comment: Import the swift file in your objective c project and then only its accessable from objective c

Comment: In `objective-c` it will be `[myViewController setMyVarTrue];`. Welcome back to `objective-c` from `swift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to clean and rebuild the project. Xcode generates the swift bridging header automatically and in my case it was stopping the build process with a (variable/method not found) error prior to regenerating the bridging header.

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC11MyProject25MyViewController")
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MBProgressHUD * _Nonnull progressIndicator;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString * _Nullable)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle * _Nullable)nibBundleOrNil OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)submitProgressHandler:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notification;
- (void)submitSuccessHandler;
- (void)submitFailureHandler:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notification;
- (void)subscribe;
- (void)unsubscribe;
@end
```

Now it works fine:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC11MyProject25MyViewController")
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MBProgressHUD * _Nonnull progressIndicator;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL closing;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString * _Nullable)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle * _Nullable)nibBundleOrNil OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setClosingTrue;
- (void)submitProgressHandler:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notification;
- (void)submitSuccessHandler;
- (void)submitFailureHandler:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notification;
- (void)subscribe;
- (void)unsubscribe;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

1. add @objc to declaration of your class
2. add a file named "yourName-swift.h", which should containt `@class yourClass;`
3. import "yourName-swift.h" in Objective C file, where you want to call

your swift class